# Discord-Bot sends random Picture from a Folder on my Desktop (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

i am building a Discordbot for my friends at the moment.
With the command !meme the Discord Bot sends a meme into the Chat.

It works, but only if the Bot-file and the Memes.png are in the same folder :/

```
    randommessage = ["Here you go:", "This one is good:", "Classic one:"]
    await message.channel.send(f"{random.choice(randommessage)}")
    memes = glob.glob("*.png")
    random_meme = random.choice(memes)
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(random_meme))

DiscordBOT  
│ │ ├───.idea  
│ │ │ └───inspectionProfiles  
│ │ ├───Code-Backup  
│ │ ├───Memes_bot_v1 (The Memes are stored in this folder)
│ │ ├───Pythonbot.py
```

Is it / How is it possible to store the Memes in another folder and the Bot can send them?

Thanks

Comment: Please include an example file structure as there can be multiple solutions depending on it. As well, does this question need to be about discord bots or is it simply a question about getting a list of `.png` files from different folders? Decontextualizing your question often makes it easier to find a solution.

Comment: DiscordBOT
│   │   ├───.idea
│   │   │   └───inspectionProfiles
│   │   ├───Code-Backup
│   │   └───Memes_bot_v1

(The Pythonbot.py is also stored in this folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, glob.glob is looking only for files in the same directory as your Pythonbot.py. Also, it doesn't return the full path of these file, but rather just their names.

Depending on what you prefer there might be many different solutions to your problem. For instance, we can add the sub-directory in the glob argument to fix the first issue and use os.path.abspath to get the absolute path of these files.

Here is an example:

```
import os
import glob

randommessage = ["Here you go:", "This one is good:", "Classic one:"]
await message.channel.send(f"{random.choice(randommessage)}")
meme_file_paths = [os.path.abspath(_) for _ in glob.glob("Memes_bot_v1/*.png")]
random_meme = random.choice(meme_file_paths)
await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(random_meme))
```